# IOC container & accessing Implementation from the container

Tags: java, c, spring, inversion-of-control, service-locator

## Background

As mentioned in this [article](http://www.baeldung.com/inversion-control-and-dependency-injection-in-spring),

> Inversion of Control can be **achieved** through various mechanisms such as: **Strategy design pattern**, **Service Locator pattern(SLP)**, **Factory pattern**, and **Dependency Injection (DI)**.

Am missing clarity in above statement, because below is my understading.

**1) Creation of container**

Creating a *dependency container* or *IOC container* **does not require** any of these design patterns(mentioned above). We need these design patterns to get **access to an implementation** from that container(which is already created). [Here is the C code](https://github.com/shamhub/Systems_programming_C/blob/master/10_C_layers_arch/DESIGN3/UI.C) where `init_handlers()` create a container(`imagehandlers` in [config.c](https://github.com/shamhub/Systems_programming_C/blob/master/10_C_layers_arch/DESIGN3/CONFIG.C)) of implementations that are configured in [config.txt](https://github.com/shamhub/Systems_programming_C/blob/master/10_C_layers_arch/DESIGN3/CONFIG.TXT)

**2) Access impl from the container**

To get access to an implementation from the container, for example,

One can rely on injection mechanism that is implementated using *DI pattern*.

or

Rely on service location mechanism that is implemented using *Service locator pattern*. [Here is the C code](https://github.com/shamhub/Systems_programming_C/blob/master/10_C_layers_arch/DESIGN3/UI.C) where `displayMenu()` locates the service from `imagehandlers` container, based on given input(`scanf("%s",filename);`)

---

So, *Dependency Injection* or *Service locator pattern* has **nothing to do** with creation of IOC container **but to get access** to an implementation from that container.

For example, In [Spring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework),

```
ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Springbeans.xml")
```

create the IOC container with singleton instances of all beans configured in `Springbeans.xml` assuming the beans are not prototype-scoped and

```
MessageBean mBean = (MessageBean)appContext.getBean("messagebean");
```

locates the `messageBean` service using service locator pattern from `appContext` container.

1) For this line of code `ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Springbeans.xml")` that creates a dependency container, Is it right to say that, creation of container has nothing to do with design pattern(like DI or SLP)?

2) Why `appContext` is not called a *dependency container*? Instead, why `appContext` is called *IOC container*?

Answer (score 1):

Unity, for example,  *is* referred to as a dependency injection container

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647202.aspx

Microsoft get it right again, this is why you should never use java.

I think it would be fair to say that a DI Container is, at least in part, the *implementation* of the patterns you list.

Say I have a class set up to have a service injected

```
class myClass
{
    myClass(IService s)
}
```

I can, and probably would in most cases, simply instantiate it 'manually' in code

```
main(string[] args)
{
    var m = new myClass(service);
}
```

However. If im working in a framework of some kind, often I wont be coding the low level structure of the app. Just Views, ViewModels, Controllers, Behaviours or some other object types which the framework itself will instantiate as needed.

In this case I don't have the opportunity to code that instanciation. Instead I need to provide the framework with some factory methods, so that when it creates my classes it can inject whatever is required.

Rather than hand code a factory for each class I can use reflection to create a generic factory that can create any class. This is the IoC or DI Container object.

Comment: Would you also like to comment on my first question?

Comment: your question is a bit vague. I don't really understand what it is you are looking for

Comment: For this line of code `ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Springbeans.xml")` that creates a dependency container, my first question asks, Is it right to say that, creation of container has nothing to do with design pattern(like DI or SLP)?

Comment: I've added some stuff.

Comment: you mean, on creation of container, all the dependencies and their dependencies thru constructor/setter injection are ready as shown [here](https://dzone.com/tutorials/java/spring/spring-ioc-1.html). This syntax `public void setQuizMaster(QuizMaster quizMaster){}`gets executed amidst creation of container, which requires container to provide its dependency as mentioned in xml

Comment: that makes no sense

Answer (score 1):

A **IoC/DI Container** is a framework for managing dependencies of an application.Since it is a framework it should define a way of creating, and loading/injecting particular dependencies when and where required. So the part

> **1) Creation of container**
>
> Creating a dependency container or IOC container does not require any of 
>   these design patterns(mentioned above)...

is not right per se, since you are refering to an object creation while a framework describes a way of achieving a certain goal, i.e the steps, design patterns and mechanisms.

The use of dependency injection mechanism, in fact makes the term *dependency injection container* more appropriate, so i would agree with your second thought. Dependency injection is a way-mechanism for achieving **IoC**  and **dependency inversion**.

For further reading and better understanding i suggest you take a look at the links below:

1. [Difference between “Inversion of Control”, “Dependency inversion” and “Decoupling”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3912504/difference-between-inversion-of-control-dependency-inversion-and-decouplin)
2. [What is IoC Container or DI Container](http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/dependencyinjection/what-is-ioc-container-or-di-container)
3. [Understanding Inversion of Control, Dependency Injection and Service Locator](http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/dependencyinjection/understanding-inversion-of-control-dependency-injection-and-service-locator)

Answer (score 1):

> 1. For this line of code ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Springbeans.xml") that creates a dependency container, Is it right to say that, creation of container has nothing to do with design pattern(like DI or SLP)?

This thing is a Service Locator. But the anti pattern with service locators is to spread them around. Keep this only in your composition root (typically main) and it's fine.

> 2. Why appContext is not called a dependency container? Instead, why appContext is called IOC container?

IOC depends on polymorphism. That requires not knowing exactly what you're talking to. That's being accomplished here by forcing you to [separate construction code from behavior code](http://www.netobjectives.net/files/books/esad/essential-skills-separate-use-from-construction.pdf) in the most extreme way possible. By making construction happen in a different language (typically xml). That separation keeps the using code from knowing exactly what it's talking to.

I could dump a bunch of things I depend on in a collection and call it a dependency container. They likely wanted a name that indicated they'd done more work than that.

Comment: Ok. I see *Dependency injection* pattern used amidst creation of IOC container, Where are *servicelocator* and *strategy pattern* used? amidst creation of container?

Comment: I'm saying `appConext` is a service locator. You should only use `getBean()` in one place high up the call stack (typically main) to avoid the anti-pattern.

Comment: Where does *strategy pattern* get used?